# Unity : calculating rotated object's position

Tags: unity-game-engine

[image]

How can I get a position of P in the right picture?

I want to know programmatic way, not unity editor skill.

Comment: Do you know the values of a & b? Did you know P's position before rotation?

Comment: Also, you need to know the angle of rotation. Given that, you can find P's position using vector cross product method.

Comment: if you are really rotating a gameobject rather than an vector just call transform.position